# Theorem regarding the total variation measure

Tags: measure-theory

My question relates to the proof of Theorem 6.13 (Chapter 6, Complex Measures, page 125) from Walter Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis (Third Edition).

Given:

$ds = g dp$ and
$ds = h d|s|$

Where:

1. $p$ is a positive measure on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak M$
2. $g$ and $h$ belong to $L^1(p)$
3. $|s|$ is the total variation measure corresponding to the measure $s$
4. $|h| = 1$

How does Rudin conclude that:

$d|s| = \bar{h} g ~dp$

Any thoughts will be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set the two expressions equal to one another:

$g \mathrm{d}p = h\mathrm{d} |s| $

2. Then multiply both sides by $h'$:

$h' g \mathrm{d}p = |h| \mathrm{d} |s| $

3. simplify using the fact that |h|=1:

$h' g \mathrm{d}p = \mathrm{d} |s| $

**Edit: justification of the above steps**

$ g \mathrm{d}p = h\mathrm{d} |s| $  as measures, so $ \int_E f g \mathrm{d}p = \int_E f h\mathrm{d} |s| $ for every measurable function $f$ and every measurable set $E$. In particular, for $f = h'$, $ \int_E h' g \mathrm{d}p = \int_E h' h\mathrm{d} |s| $. Therefore,  $ \int_E h' g \mathrm{d}p = \int_E \mathrm{d} |s| $ for every measurable $E$. Hence $h' g \mathrm{d}p = \mathrm{d} |s| $.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wish I could do that :) However, since "ds = g dp" is just a short form for saying: "s(E) = Lebesgue integral of g with respect to the measure p for every measurable set E in the sigma algebra M", one cannot multiply both sides by any function (in this case h').

Comment: Thanks for adding the justification, however given that g and h belong to L1(p), "gdp" and "hd|s|" are complex measures, and therefore one cannot  integrate f with respect to "gdp" over E and equate it to the integral of f with respect "hd|s|" over E. Note: At this point in Rudin's text, integration over complex measures has not even been defined.

Comment: Actually, I just checked the book, and your first comment is incomplete. $ds=g dp$ means that $\int f ds = \int f g dp$ for every  measurable $f$; see the remark following Theorem 1.29. And integration of complex functions was defined in chapter 1.

Comment: That is ONLY for a  positive measure. In this case, "gdp" and "hd|s|" are complex measures.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by decomposing the complex measures "gdp" and "hd|s|" into 4 positive measures (each) and then applying theorem 1.29 to each of the positive measures and h' (by splitting h' into 4 non negative measurable functions using h' = u1 - u2 + i(v1 - v2) where u1, u2, v1 and v2 are real and non negative.

Thanks for the comments.